# itextsharp: default pdfptable filling

Tags: vb.net, itext

if i define a table like this:

```
 Dim datatable As PdfPTable = New PdfPTable(4)
```

and i dont have 4 cells to add in it, how can i make it so that it automatically fills the cell if there are not enough cells?

i am finding that unless i have at least 4 cells in there, it wont display it

the question is how do i figure out which cells are blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about filling with empty Cells?

**Edit**
Something like:

```
yourPdfPTable.AddCell(yourEmptyPdfPCell)
```

Where `yourEmptyPdfPCell` is a cell with an empty string.

Comment: i remember there's a function that does this do u know?

Comment: With the PdfPTable.AddCell(PdfPCell) method.

Answer (score 2):

Something like, figure out programmatically which cells are blank, and then for those cells:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable pt = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable(100);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell cBlank = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
pt.AddCell(cBlank);
```

Comment: the question is how do i figure out which cells are blank?

Comment: this is actually helpful but can u give me this in vb.net?

Comment: I can't answer for the blanks - that's dependent on how you generate your document and I don't know how you're doing that.  

An online converter will do for the translation.  Try something like http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/